# Django Rest frame work where apply logic and how

Tags: python-3.x, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am building RestApi And i have this following model with three attribute.

```html
class Post(models.Model):


    Score=models.IntegerField()
    PName = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    productName =models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.PName
```

and i would like to match PName to ProductName and generate some score which i achived by fuzzy logic.

```html
Pname,ProductName,score
"Nike Flip-flop","Nike Flip Flop Size 8",86
"Nike Flip-Flop","Puma Flip size 9",45
"Puma Running shoe","Puma Running shoe",100
"puma Running shoe","Puma Flip flop",40
```

however i don't know how to present result in this form where user pass the request of PName ='Nike Flip Flop' whose score higher to low

```html
{
    "id": 3,
    "Score": 100,
    "productName": "Nike Flip Flop"
}
{
    "id": 6,
    "Score": 60,
    "productName": "Nike Running shoe"
}
{   "id": 50,
    "Score": 45,
    "productName": "Puma flop size 8"
}
```

.

here user pass the request as "A" and response should be the "B" attribute and "c".i would like to know how to design the view.py for this Function.Currently i Have this data in CSV format so how to import data in model? Any suggestion or any guide line how to build this function.I am using Django rest Frame work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the github [repo](https://github.com/kapeed2091/products_django_rest_api). I have written a sample view which can be used as reference.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. apart from this do you know how to write view for building forms and in Django REST API format?

Comment: There are many ways to write a REST API. Check the [link](https://github.com/kapeed2091/products_django_rest_api/blob/master/products/views.py) for a sample one.

For further assistance, refer to [DRF](django-rest-framework.org)

Answer (score 1):

For DRF you could use [SearchFilter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) and [OrderingFilter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter) to filter the dataset and order it.

For data importing you could use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to read the file and then add them to DB